# Mysql problemas com DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, delete

Estou com falhas no mysql ao reconhecer a função delete

```
 $code = '1234';

 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root');
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code='.$code.'');
 $stmt->execute();

 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

   foreach($result as $row) {

 extract($id);

 $del = "DELETE FROM codes WHERE id = '".$id."'";

 //$id é o id da coluna do BD
   }
 }
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico em relação as suas dificuldades? De quais falhas esta falando?

Comment: @gato , o mysql nao retorna nada na função DELETE eu fiz um var dump nas variaveis e elas me retorna, mas parece que a funçao nao funciona

Comment: Esse `extract($id)` não deveria ser `extract($row)`? E como você está executando o comando `DELETE`? Na pergunta você apenas o definiu como *string*, mas não o executou.

Comment: o pq dessas duas chavetas de fechamento  }  ?

Comment: Só faltou mandar executar    $conn->exec($del);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está colocando a string com o código a ser executado porém não o executou, adicione as linhas abaixo, abaixo da variável $del

```
if ($conn->query($del) === TRUE) {
    echo "Apagado com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Error ao apagar: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, esqueci desse detalhe!!

Answer (score 0):

Caso necessite percorrer uma consulta para encontrar o id que quer excluir, faça assim:

```
$rs = $con->query(“SELEC id, nome, email FROM pessoa”);
while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  if ($row->email == 'fulano@site.com' ) {
      $id = $row->id;
  }
}
```

Para realizar um DELETE com o PDO:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE idpessoa = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```